# Variable not initialized

Tags: java, variables, initialization

I'm trying to write a method for doubling vowels of a string that the user enters. I keep getting warnings that the variable output is not initialized. 
What should be done?

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String input;
    String output;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter string:");
    input =scan.nextLine();
    for (int i=0 ; i< input.length(); i++) {
        if((input.charAt(i)+"").toUpperCase().matches("A|E|I|O|U")) {
            output += input.charAt(i);
        }
        output += input.charAt(i);
        System.out.println ("New string:" +output);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please use StringBuilder for the output.

Answer (score 5):

You must initialize `output`, since local variables don't have default values :

```
String output = "";
```

Otherwise, in the first call to `output += input.charAt(i);` (which is equivalent to `output = output + input.charAt(i);`), `output` is not initialized, and therefore this line has a compilation error.

With `input` you don't have the same problem, since you are assigning a value to it before first trying to access it.

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize *local variables* in Java in order to avoid of compilation errors because they are not set by default. So just initialize before access them:

```
String input = "";
String output = "";
```

Comment: `if you don't initialize their reference values during execution, you'll have nulls instead - no default values.` Wrong. You have `null` if **and only if** the variable is declared at class-level. If the variable is declared within a method, it does **not** have a default value, hence the "Variable might not have been initialized" warning.

Comment: This is still wrong. Now it's wrong in the opposite direction. Fields are initialised to default values, variables are not. So you're only expected to get this error in the case of a variable, not a field.

Answer (score 0):

Simply initialize your strings:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "";
    String output = "";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter string:");
    input = scan.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if ((input.charAt(i) + "").toUpperCase().matches("A|E|I|O|U")) {
            output += input.charAt(i);
        }
        output += input.charAt(i);
        System.out.println("New string:" + output);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you declare a string:

```
String str; // The string is declared  

str = "whatever" // The string is initialized  

 String string = "whatever" // The string is initialized and declared`
```